# Question about Hartogs' theorem proof

Tags: set-theory

Is it possible to prove this theorem without the use the replacement axiom??

Answer (score 3):

If by "Hartogs' Theorem" you mean

> For each well-orderable cardinal $\kappa$, there is a least well-orderable cardinal $\lambda$ such that $\kappa<\lambda$

then the answer is **no**; we need Replacement. Specifically, we need Replacement to prove that there is no *largest* well-orderable cardinal! If $V\models ZFC$, then $V_{\omega+\omega}$ satisfies all of ZFC except replacement - but every ordinal in $V_{\omega+\omega}$ is countable! So in $V_{\omega+\omega}$, there is no well-orderable cardinal greater than $\aleph_0$.

Note, however, that in $V_{\omega+\omega}$ there *is* a well-orderable *set* which is uncountable - namely, the set of all well-ordered relations on $\omega$, modulo "same order type"! Set theory without Replacement is *weird*.

Comment: *Hartogs'* theorem can also be stated in the language of orders, so for every set there is a well-ordered set which does not inject into it. Then we get the theorem from very few axioms.

Comment: @AsafKaragila A very good point. (And thanks for the spelling correction!)